# will "Install ubuntu on a hard disk" also install all changes in persistent partition?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, portable

I used "universal USB installer" and created a portable Ubuntu system in my USB flash drive with persistence partition of 4GB, in which I installed some additional softwares. If I use "Install Ubuntu on a hard disk" feature with this flash drive, will all my changes in the persistent partition also be installed in the hard disk?

Currently I do not have a free hard drive so I cannot try it by myself.

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is that?

Comment: I am now trying to use the latest, 16.04

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not. It will be a vanilla install.

Although you **can** still accomplish what you are after: [Install persistent version of USB onto a hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719311/install-persistent-version-of-usb-onto-a-hard-drive)