# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 with install from persistent USB

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, usb, persistence

How would I go about dual booting my Windows 10 system with Ubuntu 16.04.2 while keeping the changes made to my persistent Ubuntu USB?

I have tried searching all over for this but all I found was this: [Install persistent version of USB onto a hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719311/install-persistent-version-of-usb-onto-a-hard-drive?newreg=fabfe6e3409242b78c8d688873ebb0b1)

Do I just follow the normal dual boot installation and then boot to the persistent usb, use the command from the above post (dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sda) and replacing /dev/sda with /dev/sdaX where X is the partition number I want to store Ubuntu on?

I will also add that the persistent USB contains both Ubuntu 16.04.2 and Kali Linux 2017.1 booted with Easy2Boot.

Comment: Every time you need to use Ubuntu, just boot from USB, that's all.

Comment: @mikewhatever I know that, but my USB drive is not that big and I am about to run out of space, therefore I would like to install it alongside Windows while keeping my data.

Comment: Don't know if such a scenario is covered. You could use the /dev/sdaX thing to copy the USB to a partition, but it's unclear how you'd boot it. Using the command as is will overwrite parts of Windows, so not recommended. The second answer to that question looks promising, though not upvoted.

Comment: @mikewhatever I also found a post on an Ubuntu forum on backing up your system with tar. This might be something to try?

Comment: If you're just concerned about getting any data files off of the USB drive, just build a normal dual-boot to your HDD, then boot Ubuntu from the HDD, insert the USB drive, and manually copy off the required data files.

Comment: @heynnema I want to keep my programs and packages as well but I'm not sure where they are located.

Comment: Recommended to just reinstall the apps once you get Ubuntu up and running. However, `Synaptic` has a way to create a list of installed apps, and you can use that list to reinstall those apps on your Ubuntu install but there can be some negative side effects. See `man synaptic` or Google it.